# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Domain.DataModel.Hospital'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to get list of data with linq but I am getting this error.

Shortly my problem is:

I have a `Hospital` model. And this model consists of city code.All city code is in decimal type.(1,2,3,4,.. etc.)

Also I have a `Person` and `PersonStatu` models.Person and PersonStatu related with `TcKimlik` property.And `Hospital` model related with `PersonStatu`'s `HospitalCode` property.

So when I try to get to hospitals by city code , if city code greater than 10 it works.But when it less then 10 it couldnt return any data.And it occurs this error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Domain.DataModel.Hospital'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

**Here is My `Hospital` Model:**

```
[Table("SPTS.HOSPITALS")]
public partial class Hospital
{
         ....

    public decimal? IL_KODU { get; set; }

        ....

}
```

Here is My Querable LINQ queries:

```
   var hospitals = context.Hospitals.Where(p=>p.IL_KODU==1);


    var persons = (from c in context.Persons
                   join x in context.PersonStatus on c.TcKimlik equals x.Tckn
                   join h in hospitals on x.HospitalCode equals h.KURUM_KODU
                   where x.Statu == true
                   select new DataViewModel
                   {
                       Id = c.Id,
                       TcKimlik = c.TcKimlik,
                       Uyruk = c.Uyruk,
                       Ad = c.Ad,
                       Soyad = c.Soyad,
                       Cinsiyet = c.Cinsiyet,
                       DogumTarihi = c.DogumTarihi,
                       KurumStatu = h.PAYDAS,
                       KurumKodu = h.KURUM_KODU,
                       KurumAdi = h.KURUM_ADI,
                       BranchName = c.Brans.BranchName,
                       AcademicTitleName = c.AkademikUnvan.Title,
                       ManagerialTitleName = c.IdariUnvan.Title,
                       StaffStatuName = c.Durum.Statu,
                       BranchTypeName = c.Unvan.Type,
                       ServiceClassName = c.Unvan.ServiceClass.Name,
                       City = h.KURUM_ILI,
                       CityCode = h.IL_KODU,
                       CityTownName = h.KURUM_ILCESI
                   }).AsQueryable();
```

So what can I do to solve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem begins from this line:

```
var hospitals = context.Hospitals.Where(p=>p.IL_KODU==1);
```

This line creates `IQueryable` collection from `Hospitals` data context which `IL_KODU` matches 1, hence you can't simply perform joining sets of data on database context with another sets of data saved on memory.

To handle `Hospitals` collection using multiple joins, based from "[Showing Unable to create a constant value of type ''. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436439/showing-unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-only-primitive-types-suc)", put `Where` method directly on second join instead:

```
var persons = (from c in context.Persons
               join x in context.PersonStatus 
               on c.TcKimlik equals x.Tckn 
               join h in context.Hospitals.Where(p => p.IL_KODU == 1) // where clause added here using database context
               on x.HospitalCode equals h.KURUM_KODU
               where x.Statu == true
               select new DataViewModel
               {
                       Id = c.Id,
                       TcKimlik = c.TcKimlik,
                       Uyruk = c.Uyruk,
                       Ad = c.Ad,
                       Soyad = c.Soyad,
                       Cinsiyet = c.Cinsiyet,
                       DogumTarihi = c.DogumTarihi,
                       KurumStatu = h.PAYDAS,
                       KurumKodu = h.KURUM_KODU,
                       KurumAdi = h.KURUM_ADI,
                       BranchName = c.Brans.BranchName,
                       AcademicTitleName = c.AkademikUnvan.Title,
                       ManagerialTitleName = c.IdariUnvan.Title,
                       StaffStatuName = c.Durum.Statu,
                       BranchTypeName = c.Unvan.Type,
                       ServiceClassName = c.Unvan.ServiceClass.Name,
                       City = h.KURUM_ILI,
                       CityCode = h.IL_KODU,
                       CityTownName = h.KURUM_ILCESI
               }).AsQueryable();
```

NB: If the modified query still won't work, try swapping `context.Persons` and `context.PersonStatus` order each other, including the `on` clause relationship between them.